# Insert elements into Array Actionscript3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have created an array with fixed size of 5, but when I try to insert element into array, the element is inserted into 6th position. Can anyone tell me how to insert value from the first place of array?

PS:Since the elements are randomly inserted, so I couldn't do something like this:songTitles[5] = "Happy Birthday";

Some references are as follows:

myRes = new Array(5);

```
     if(e.keyCode == 65){

        myRes.push(word1.getLabel());
        trace(myRes);
    } else if (e.keyCode == 83) {

        myRes.push(word2.getLabel());
        trace(myRes);

    } else if (e.keyCode == 68) {

        myRes.push(word3.getLabel());
        trace(myRes);

    } else if (e.keyCode == 70) {

        myRes.push(word4.getLabel());
        trace(myRes);

    } else if (e.keyCode == 71) {

        myRes.push(word5.getLabel());
        trace(myRes);

    }
```

The Result I get:

,,,,,A
,,,,,A,S
,,,,,A,S,F

Comment: Is there a reason why you gave it a length of 5 when declaring the Array?

Comment: It is required by the project criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try 
myRes = new Array();
When you create an array with a fixed size flash fills it with empty values. If you don't want your arrays length to exceed 5, just insert a conditional checking the length into your keyboardevent handler function.

Comment: yeah, I can do it that way as well. could I ask u one more question?Basically, I got three classes -- main , function1 and function2(array). I defined the value of an array in main. In function1, I need to call function2 with parameter of the array in main. So how can I pass array from main to function1?

Comment: Calling your classes functions might be misleading. Also try using Capital letters for classes. 

function1 would need a reference to the array declared in main, you can pass it to the class beforehand. Do you really have to call function2 from function1? Simplifying your classes might be a bit of work now, but save you time in the end.

Comment: declare it in function1:
`public var mainArray:Array;`
give it value in main:
`function1.mainArray = myRes;`